# List divider with 3 color layers like the this screenshot?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a list divider that has an etched look like the attached screenshot. Upon closer inspection, I see that the divider is composed of 3 layers of colors, 2A2A2A, 3A3A3A and 404040. Does anyone have a clue as to how to implement this. I tried to do it with a layer-list, but it does not have a field for color or background

```
<item android:color ?? >
```

Quick help is appreciated.

[image: Etched divider]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a shape that has a height of 3 pixels with a vertical gradient.

Here is an **UNTESTED EXAMPLE**

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <size android:height="3dp"/>
     <gradient 
          android:angle="90" 
          android:startColor="#2A2A2A" 
          android:centerColor="#3A3A3A" 
          android:endColor="#404040" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks Sherif. I tried what you suggested, but the divider doesn't look the same. I think the colors need to be 3 separate rectangles and not blended evenly.

Comment: @user720954 try to use 3px instead of 3dp

Comment: Still no difference. The layers blend together and hence doesn't look as sharp as the one in the image attached.